# como establecer variable y metodos globales para todas las actividades enn kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Un saludo a todos...
Quiero declarar ciertas variables globales que puedan ser llamas por cualquier activity en kotlin.
por otra parte estas variables cambiaran cada momento de valor pues un metodo debe hacerlo( son coordenadas de ubicacion del celular).
La pregunta es... donde puedo hacer mi metodo para que sea generico... y tambien donde puedo declarar las variables globales... para que puedan ser accedidas desde cualquier actividad ?

Espero puedan orientarme... gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un folder llamado `utilities` y alli crear tu clase con funciones de uso global, por ejemplo el siguiente archivo de clase llamado `Utils.tk`, el cual contiene una funcion "global" para mostrar un cuadro de dialogo

```
class Utils { 
     fun showDialog(context: Activity, message: String) {
         val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
         builder.setTitle ............
     }
}
```

Y luego puedes llamarlo desde tus `activities`

```
import com.tupaquete.app.utilities.*
....
Utils.showDialog(this, "Cargando productos")
```

Para tus variables globales, quiza puedas utilizar sharePreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podrias crear una clase con un Companion object con las variables y metodos que necesites:

```
class Coordenadas {
companion object {
    var x_coord: Float = 0f
    var y_coord: Float = 0f
    fun calcula(){
        println(x_coord * y_coord)
    }
}
```

}

que serian accesibles con:

`Coordenadas.x_coord
Coordenadas.y_coord
Coordenadas.calcula()`